# how to type < and > in a window 7 french keyboad?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard

In windows 7 french keyboard diagram, < and > seems is between shift and W key:

[image]

But on my bloomberg keyboard, there's nothing between left shift key and W!

[image]

how would one type < and > in french keyboard?

Comment: It’s probably the key above Enter. But really, why not just try them all? It’s a matter of seconds.

Answer (score -2):

In French keyboard, `<` and `>` are given in place of `Z`. Try `Shift + Z` for `>` and `Z` for `<`.

I hope it would help you.

Comment: that's when i 'm using default keyboard - english. the question is about when i switched to french, how could i type < and >.

Comment: switching to French switches the keyboard diagram to figure 1?

Comment: yeah, so comes the question...

Comment: okay, then try `Shift + Z` of the keyboard after switching to the French.

Comment: @athos, did it worked or not??